# What scale of shutter speeds actually lies behind the numbers?

Tags: shutter

On nearly every camera I've used, the scale of shutter speeds goes something like:

1s, 1/2s, 1/4s, 1/8s, 1/15s, 1/30s, 1/60s, 1/120s, 1/250s, 1/500s, 1/1000s, 1/2000s

whereas clearly a scale of halves actually runs:

1s, 1/2s, 1/4s, 1/8s, 1/16, 1/32s, 1/64s, 1/128s, 1/256s, 1/512s, 1/1024s, 1/2048s.

That's close enough, but still, there's a difference, and I imagine that with high-precison electronic shutters it's quite possible to be right on the mark with timings.

Where on the scales are the marked, nominal values generally intended to be true (i.e. where are the shutter makers aiming for true accuracy, even if it's only an aim):

- along the *up to 1/8s range* (where they match the actual scale of halves)
- along the *1/15-1/120s range* (where they are off at a ratio of 0.9375)
- along the *1/250s and faster range* (where they are off at a ratio of 0.9765625)?

I am well aware that mechanical and even electronic tolerances may in most circumstances render quibbles over tiny fractions of a second moot. I am equally well aware that many of the scales and numbers used in photography are convenient approximations, and not intended to be taken at face value.

Even so, the fact remains that in design and manufacture an approximation of an ideal still requires a conception of that ideal. Just because a standard is an ideal and can't be met, or it doesn't really matter if it's not met, doesn't mean that design and manufacture don't need ideals, or don't work with them.

I *guess* that the point of truth in the shutter timings scale is *1s=1s*, and all the other numbers are allowed to be approximations if necessary, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Neither that question nor its answers address the issue raised here: Since they can't *all* be true to life, **at which point along these scales are the nominal values intended to represent reality**?

Comment: It is addressed *from a photography point of view*: it doesn't matter.

Comment: Of course it matters, because no matter (ever-decreasing) limits of real-world tolerance, designers and manufacturers still work towards ideal values. I'd like to know what those ideal values are. I presume that 1s=1s is supposed to be the point of truth, but I'd like to know. And it also matters in practice: if 1s is a 'true' value, then we also have timing points at 2, 4, 8, 16 seconds. If 1/120s is a 'true' value, then a supposed 16-second exposure is actually over 17 seconds. Tough luck in that case if you were to set up a system to trigger a 16-second exposure every 16 seconds....

Comment: I'm confused - in what photographic scenario would it actually matter if the exposure were 16 vs 17 seconds and tripped as soon as possible after the last frame? (Outside of a lab/science experiment, of course)

Comment: @Hueco e.g. I want to make a series of 16-second exposures, so I set the shutter speed to 16s, and a timer to trigger a shutter release every (say) 16.2s, so that almost immediately one has ended, another starts. If the expected 16s exposure is longer than the timer interval (say: 17.07s, so the timer fails to trigger a new exposure and we have to wait another 16 seconds for it to fire again), the result will be a series of ~15s gaps in the record.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Correct. Consumer (including "professional") digital cameras are not precison measuring devices.

Comment: @DanieleProcida, will be wise to adopt 180-degree shutter rule from video. And no mechanical device is perfect. And do not need to be.

Comment: But why are those gaps bad? If you're shooting a time lapse, those gaps will hardly matter in the end. What are you shooting where it would matter? Is there an actual photographic context (I'm curious) or are you simply using a consumer product as a precision (haha) measuring device?

Comment: @Hueco who knows? That was an example to answer your question. My question is posted above, and remains, so far, unanswered.

Comment: What part isn't covered by, say, Wayne's answers to both this question and the other one?

Comment: @DanieleProcida What part of one second as the basis of the entire scale and the historical background for the rounding of other numbers is not covered in the answers to the other question? The third sentence of the highest voted answer is **"Start with 1 second and keep dividing it by 2."** The next highest answer begins by pointing out that the *actual* shutter times are all based on the powers of 2. (2 to the power of 0 is 1).

Comment: There are also more than one answer to the other question that cover the historical background for it.

Answer (score 1):

For each stop to be precisely 2x steps, the only possible actual precise shutter speed goals are necessarily these:

1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/512, 1/1024 etc seconds.

For full seconds:  1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 seconds (sequential powers of 2)

The camera markings are just nominal numbers for convenience (close, but existing in name only, but not actual or real). The camera shows us humans the nominal numbers, but it always tries its best to meet the exact goals of precise 2x steps.

I am NOT saying the camera mechanisms are always precisely accurate, but their goal is these precise numbers. And shutter speeds are pretty accurate today, via digital computer chips and focal plane shutters.

This "nominal marking" concept is true of shutter speed, f/stops, and ISO values.
We are shown rounded approximate markings, but the camera goals are the precise 2x steps. Probably we humans can more easily recognize 2x steps by using the nominal numbers.

Complete charts of all of those exact numbers
and the plan to compute them (third stops, etc),
and the answer to your precise question, are shown at my site at
https://www.scantips.com/lights/fstop2.html

Comment: I don't know whether to +1 for the accurate answer or -1 for making me read a page of numbers I'm never going to really need to know ;))

Comment: Thanks. :)  I'd guess everyone has wondered about the jumps in the nominal shutter speed sequence, like this OP's question. But you're right,  it does not affect our taking pictures, nominal is a good enough concept. However any time we attempt computing things, like EV, or tenth f/stops, or even Guide Numbers, the accurate numbers actually used do become important.

Comment: As a 'modern, computer-aware human' I grok powers of two & work with them all day, every day, even to question if someone means GB or GiB . As a photographer, I don't give a sh... if the numbers are 'accurate'  ;)

Comment: @WayneF "any time we attempt computing things... the accurate numbers actually used do become important" - one prompt for my question is that I have built a Canonet QL17 GIII simulator in Python, in a Jupyter Notebook. I have assumed the scale's nominal 1s is intended to be an actual 1s, and that the other figures follow from that.

Comment: Yes, because precisely 1.000 second is the base of the sequence  ... because 2 to power of 0 is 1.   2 to power 1 is 2, and 2 to power 2 is 4, etc. Starting at other than 1 second would be nonsensical, not how humans count. Same with f/stops, square root of 2 to power of 0 is f/1, and to power 1 is f/1.414.  And, 1 second at f/1 is EV 0.  1 is the base.

Comment: @WayneF If you add that to your reply (minus judgemental remarks about what you think is nonsensical) I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: It is of course already the answer, and powers of 2 is specifically tediously included in the link, but suit yourself if you don't understand it.  Curious, what other shutter sequence base choice would you possibly consider?  Zero maybe might seem superficially reasonable as a generic base of a sequence of numbers, except zero is not a satisfactory shutter exposure, and for a sequence of powers of 2, 2 to power of 0 is instead 1.

Answer (score 1):

For technical reasons and aesthetics, a 2X increment of exposure change is considered the “norm”. This doubling or halving of the exposure energy applies to both the aperture and the shutter speed adjustments. However in modern times a finer increment is often used.

To appreciate the shutter speed number set, one should reflect on the fact that initially the mechanisms of the shutter are escapements. In other words, they are akin to the pocket watch which uses an impulse action called an escapement  driven by spring action. These mechanisms used various gear ratios that  present various possibilities for an exposure duration. Simplicity of design takes precedence.

So what is the error percentage setting 1/30 of a second vs. 1/32 of a second or 1/60 vs. 1/64? The error is about 6% ,which is zilch. Also note, it is likely impossible to set either shutter or aperture any finer that 1/3 of an f-stop.